# AWS Lambda function, pick version based on URL parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a lambda function and have versioned them v1 and v2 etc

I then have created a api endpoint using the API Gateway with a resource and post method, which currently calls the v1 version lambda

eg lambdafuction:1

My question is, how can I switch the version based on url parameter? eg if I have this: [www.endpoint.com?version=v2](http://www.endpoint.com?version=v2) would call version 2 lambda

I am aware I can create v1 and v2 resource like in the image etc and then call as mylambda:v2 but I would rather have 1 resource path and it picks based on the url param instead of creating new resource version each time

I this possible. Thanks for any help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try invoking an another lambda from a master lambda for this purpose. Like using `AWSLambdaClientBuilder` from AWS SKD for Java and redirecting the request to the vX version of the lambda or [www.endpoint.com?version=vX](http://www.endpoint.com?version=vX).  However I believe this would be like using another API Gateway.